# How to break a jquery variable dynamically based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery variable which has is showing the value in the console as  ..

```
["INCOMING", 0, "INETCALL", 0, "ISD", 31.8, "LOCAL", 197.92, "STD", 73.2]
```

Now as per my need i have to break these values and make it like this

```
["INCOMING", 0],["INETCALL", 0],["ISD", 31.8],["LOCAL", 197.92],["STD", 73.2]
```

but these values i need to make in the required formate dynamically as this is received from 
database.

Here is my ajax call to get the values from server side..

```
var dbdata="";
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'getPieChartdata',
                async:false,
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {
                   dbdata=JSON.parse(data);
                }
            });
            console.log(dbdata);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following should work as the new success function of the ajax call.  it will translate dbdata var to the desired array format assuming its already a valid array.  you should for best practices add some code before running the for loop to make sure that its both a valid array and of the format you expect.

```
            success: function(data) {
               var dbdata=JSON.parse(data);
               var i;
               var fancy_array = [];
               for(i = 0; i < dbdata.length;i=i+2)
               {
                    var item = [dbdata[i], dbdata[i+1]];
                    fancy_array.push(item);
               }
               console.log(fancy_array);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `dbdata` outside of the success callback. You'll need to do something along the lines of `success: handleData`. However, getting the data into chunks is pretty easy.

```
var data = ["INCOMING", 0, "INETCALL", 0, "ISD", 31.8, "LOCAL", 197.92, "STD", 73.2];
var chunks = [];

for( var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i += 2 ){
  chunks.push(data.slice(i, i + 2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is already answered, but here are two more snippets to look on solution from different perspectives:

```
var data = ["INCOMING", 0, "INETCALL", 0, "ISD", 31.8, "LOCAL", 197.92, "STD", 73.2];
var chunks = data.join().match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g).map(function (v, i) {
    return [v, a[1+i*2]]
})
```

```
var data = ["INCOMING", 0, "INETCALL", 0, "ISD", 31.8, "LOCAL", 197.92, "STD", 73.2];
var chunks = a.reduce(function (out, value, i, arr) {
    return out.concat.apply(out, i%2 ? null : [[[arr[i],arr[i+1]]]])
}, [])
```